# how to replace div2 with other div1 at exact same position of div1 in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div in html, clicking on a button should replace a current div with other div but at the exact same place of current div

```css
.team-intro {
margin-top:38%;
height:250px;
background-color:#7BD2FF;
/*background-image:url('images/backgrounds/download.jpg');*/
background-size:contain;

font-weight: bold;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 1.5em;
border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;

}

.team-intro p{
margin-left:27%;
margin-top: 3%;
font-size: 1.5em;
color:#ffffff;
font-weight:bolder;


}
.team-btn{
/*border:2px solid #3aa3e3;*/
border:2px solid #ffffff;
border-radius: 0.25rem;
padding: 14px 32px 16px;
position: absolute;
/*color:#3aa3e3;*/
color:#ffffff;
margin-top: 1%;
background-color:#3aa3e3;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
left:42%;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Roboto;
font-size: 1.22em;

}
.team-btn:hover{

background-color:#7BD2FF;
color: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="team-intro">
<p>XXXXX is a Free to use, Invite your team and get started today</p> </div>
<div class="team-btn">Invite Now</div>



<div calss="team-invite" style="display:none;">
<p>Invie by Email</p> 
<input type='email' id="inviteEmail"  required placeholder='Email' size="70"><br>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

I want to replace div class `team-intro` with div `team-invite` but in exact position of `team-intro p` where a Email address  text box will appear

Comment: you really could just `display: none` class1 then `display: block` class2 and it will work.

Comment: You're replacing it with an empty DIV, what do you expect to see?

Comment: @Barmar it's not empty, it's just `display: none`

Comment: @A.Lau He's replacing it with `<div class="2"></div>` which is an empty DIV. He's not replacing it with the DIV that contains `My Dynamic Content`.

Comment: @Barmar ah that's true

Comment: Edited my Question as it seems no one understands my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't moving the DIV with `class="2"`, it's creating a *new* DIV with that class. But it doesn't contain anything.

If you want to move the existing DIV, you need to use a selector, not HTML. But when you replace it, it still has `display:none;` style, so you won't see it unless you also call `.show()`

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.1').replaceWith($('.2').show());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">
  My Content 1
</div>

<div class="2" style="display:none;">
  My Dynamic Content
</div>
<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: thank you @barmar you comments are really helpful, I was creating new div instead of replacing with existing by incorrect use of `.html()` instead when I use `.replacewWth` it works fine

Answer (score 1):

The spelling of `class` is wrong on the `team-invite` div. Change the spelling and then call the following on button click

```
$('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").clone().show())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, what about the `.html()` function?

When you call `.html(TEXT)` on a selector, it inserts the passed TEXT in argument inside the selector. When you simply call `.html()` on a selector, you get its inner content.

Knowing that, you can combine both:

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.1').html($('#myHiddenDiv').html());
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="1">
    My Content 1
</div>

<div id="myHiddenDiv" class="2" style="display:none;">
    My Dynamic Content
</div>

<button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the display of the second `div` as `block` to show it.

```
$(".2").css("display", "block");
```

```js
$(function() {

      $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.1').replaceWith('<div class="2"></div>');
        $(".2").css("display", "block");
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="1">
          My Content 1
        </div>

        <div class="2" style="display:none;">
        My Dynamic Content
        </div>
        <button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi: you have set the display of class 2 as none. On replacing it with the first one. don't forget to set the display as block.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for You.
It just uses hide and show functions of jquery:-

```js
$(function() {

      $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.1').hide();
        $('.2').show();
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="1">
          My Content 1
        </div>

        <div class="2" style="display:none;">
        My Dynamic Content
        </div>
        <button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
$(function() {

      $("#btnClick").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("div.1").replaceWith('<div class="2">My Dynamic Content</div>');
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="1">
          My Content 1
        </div>

        <button id="btnClick">Click me!</button>
```